# How to add a constant number to all entries of a row in a text file in bash

Tags: bash

I want to add or subtract a constant number form all entries of a row in a text file in Bash.

eg. my text file looks like:

```
21.018000 26.107000 51.489000 71.649000 123.523000 127.618000 132.642000 169.247000 173.276000 208.721000 260.032000 264.127000 320.610000 324.639000 339.709000 354.779000 385.084000
```

(it has only one row) 
and I want to subtract value 18 from all columns and save it in a new file. What is the easiest way to do this in bash?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try the bash only and compact version in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple awk like this:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i -= 18} 1' file >> $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp file    

cat file
3.018 8.107 33.489 53.649 105.523 109.618 114.642 151.247 155.276 190.721 242.032 246.127 302.61 306.639 321.709 336.779 367.084
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of awks RS and ORS variables we can do it like this:

```
awk  'BEGIN {ORS=RS=" "}{print $1 - 18 }' your_file > your_new_filename
```

It sets the record separator for input and output to space. This makes every field a record of its own and we have only to deal with `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this compact and funny version:

```
$ printf "%s 18-n[ ]P" $(cat text.file) | dc
```

`dc` is a reverse-polish desk calculator (hehehe).

`printf` generates one string per number. The first string is `21.018000 18-n[ ]P`. Other strings follow, one per number.

`21.018000`  `18`: the values separated with spaces are pushed to the `dc` stack.

`-` Pops two values off, subtracts the first one popped from the second one popped, and pushes the result.

`n` Prints the value on the top of the stack, popping it off, and does not print a newline after.

`[ ]` add string  (space) on top of the stack.

`P` Pops off the value on top of the stack.  If it it a string, it is simply printed without a trailing newline.

The test with an additional `sed` to replace the useless last  (space) char with a new line:

```
$ printf "%s 18-n[ ]P" $(cat text.file) | dc | sed "s/ $/\n/" > new.file
$ cat new.file
3.018000 8.107000 33.489000 53.649000 105.523000 109.618000 114.642000 151.247000 155.276000 190.721000 242.032000 246.127000 302.610000 306.639000 321.709000 336.779000 367.084000
```

### ----

For history a version with `sed`:

```
$ sed "s/\([1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\)\{1,\}/\1 18-n[ ]P/g" text.file | dc
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl which will work on multiply rows:

```
perl -i -nlae '@F = map {$_ - 18} @F; print "@F"' num_file
#     ^ ^^^^                               ^
#     | ||||                               Printing an array in quotes will join
#     | ||||                               with spaces
#     | |||Evaluate code instead of expecting filename.pl
#     | ||Split input on spaces and store in @F
#     | |Remove (chomp) newline and add newline after print
#     | Read each line of specified file (num_file)
#     Inplace edit, change original file, take backup with -i.bak
```